# Entity framework not showing the correct return type of the procedure sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchData] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @searchparameter varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT cat.CategoryId,cat.CategoryImageURL,cat.CategoryName,cat.isDeleted,ap.AppCreatedBy,ap.AppCreatedOn
,ap.AppDetails,ap.AppId,ap.AppImageURL,ap.AppModifiedBy,ap.AppModifiedOn,ap.AppName,ap.isDeleted,subcat.SubCategoryId
,subcat.SubCategoryName,subcat.SubCategoryImageUrl
  FROM Category cat JOIN App ap
       ON cat.CategoryID = ap.CategoryID 
       Join SubCategory subcat ON subcat.SubCategoryId = ap.SubCategoryId   
  WHERE FREETEXT (cat.CategoryName, @searchparameter) OR  FREETEXT (subcat.SubCategoryName,@searchparameter) OR FREETEXT (ap.AppName,@searchparameter)
  OR CONTAINS (ap.AppDetails,@searchparameter) OR CONTAINS (cat.CategoryName, @searchparameter) OR  CONTAINS (subcat.SubCategoryName,@searchparameter) OR CONTAINS (ap.AppName,@searchparameter)
  OR CONTAINS (ap.AppDetails,@searchparameter) OR ap.AppName LIKE @searchparameter + '%' ORDER BY ap.AppName

END
```

But when i update the model from the database the stored procedure shows a return type of int in the entity framework though i want to return all the above values.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried completely removing the references to the procedure in your edm, then re-adding it?

Comment: yes i have tried that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored Procedures always have a return type of `int`.

You need to map this to a function returning a complex type in your entity model.

Comment: How do i do that mapping?

Comment: http://codetunnel.com/blog/post/how-to-map-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4